# can't find tensorflow local in Pycharm project Interpreters

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, macos-sierra

I am new to tensorflow,

OS: Mac 10.13.1
Python: 2.7
tensorflow: 1.4.0(install with pip)

I want to use tensorflow from Pycharm for a project, and when I open:
"Pycharm" - "Preferences" - "Project Interpreter", There are only two local:

2.7.13/(Library/Frameworks/Python.framework.Versions.2.7/bin/python2.7)
/System/Library/Frameworks.Python.framwork.Versions.2,7.bin.python2.7

I can't find tensorflow, what should I do?

Comment: tensorflow isnt an interpreter. it is a python package. just select the ```python.exe``` file for your interpreter. You should probably check out some tutorials on tensorflow to learn the basics. maybe even some basics on python

Comment: thx first, but I can't find the tensorflow package,  terminal: find tensorflow, the result is :find: tensorflow: No such file or directory, I install tensorflow with pip, is it normal?

Comment: if you installed tensorflow with pip, then it will go to your site-packages folder. probably somewhere like ```C:\Users\yourname\python27\Lib\site-packages```. If you want to use tensorflow in a python script, you import it like you do any other package.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the python 2.7 that you see. Then after you select you python you will see all the packages that come with it. One of the packages will be Tensorflow.